# for loop : C++ and python

Tags: python, c++, for-loop

I understand how to use a for loop like

```
for (x = 0 ; x<5 ; x++ ) { // some_code }
```

in C++ but what about a for loop  like

```
for x in y:
```

which exist at least in python

Comment: Are you asking, how does one iterate over a container in C++ in the same way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest equivalent is a range based for-loop. For example,

```
auto y = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

for (auto i : y)
{
  // do something with i
}
```

There are more details, but these depend on what you want to do. The C++ semantics are quite different to python's.

Comment: @SethMMorton Yes, both the use of `auto` and the range based for-loop are C++11.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can use std::for_each which can be answer for you question.
More information you can find [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/).

Answer (score 0):

The `for i in range(5)` loop would "look" for i in the `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, so it would be quite similar in working as a C++ `for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)`.

Comment: I don't think that matters. There was a question on understanding how to use the for loop in python, the example I have used is clearer to get I think, as the y would be a collection, wouldn't it?

Comment: Of course it matters, because the C++ loop you show is only equivalent to the python loop if you have a sequence of integers 0, 1, 2, ...

Comment: This is why I have used the above example. Quick thought: @user2803490 gets the C/C++ loop, so my example might help him understand the idea.