# C++ for each usable with anonymous collections?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to get some Python listcomprehension like syntax into my C++.
I am using Visual Studio 2013.

As an example, suppose I want to emulate (python): `for i in [1,5]: sum+=i`
Assume sum initialized previously to zero.

The best I could do so far is:

```
int a[]={1,5}, sum=0;
for each (int i in a) sum+=i;
```

I would have liked something like:

```
for each (int i in {1,5}) sum+=i;
```

But obviously, this does not compile; attempts to insert int or int[] at the {1, 5} do not help as far as I can see.

using the {1,5} to initialize a vector: `std::vector<int>{1,5}` works, but is a bit windy; and I don't need the overhead of constructing and destroying a vector.

Did I miss something, or is this impossible at C++11 (and mayby C++14)?

Comment: The code you are posting is not C++. Could you provide real code examples? Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157497/for-loop-c-and-python/22157535#22157535

Comment: `for each` is a [MS extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177202.aspx), and a pretty bad one at that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the earlier answer. I had not found it.
The code was, as T.C. noted, real, but MS which does not seem to carry much favor :-). The for (auto i : {1.5}) solution will work for me and I'll mark that one up. That has the least overhead while being clear.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something similar with an `std::initializer_list`. The following code compiles on gcc 4.8.2

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (auto x : {1,5}) sum += x;
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}
```

EDIT: If you want to use ranges, instead of hard-coded collections, you can use the following:

```
template <int L, int H, int... Nums> struct make_seq_impl {
    constexpr std::initializer_list<int> operator()() const {
        return make_seq_impl<L + 1, H, Nums..., L>{}();
    }
};

template <int H, int... Nums> struct make_seq_impl<H, H, Nums...> {
    constexpr std::initializer_list<int> operator()() const {
        return { Nums..., H };
    }
};

template <int L, int H>
inline constexpr std::initializer_list<int> make_seq() {
    return make_seq_impl<L, H>{}();
}

int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
    for (auto x : make_seq<1, 5>()) sum += x;
}
```

Comment: For a sum, something like `accumulate(boost::irange(1, 5), 0);` should work better given a range-based `accumulate`.

Comment: Yep, I agree. However the question was about iterating over anonymous collections, not best practices. I would probably never use the above code for anything in production. It's a neat trick, though.

Comment: @chris I was convinced there was an analytical solution to that problem ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can get very similar syntax using a range based `for` and a braced-init-list

```
int sum = 0;
for(auto i : {1,2,3,4}) {
    sum += i;
}
```

Or use [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

```
auto arr = {1,2,3,4};
auto sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int x : std::array<int, 2>{1, 5})
        sum += x;
}
```

It retains the longwindedness, but there's very little overhead in creating the array.